# replace in javascript with case conversion

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to make the first character of every word in a string to uppercase.
i am referring to this article [Replacement Text Case Conversion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html).

when i am running the regular expression **([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*(\s)*)** with the replacement text as **\u$1\l$2** in my editor (sublime text) it works fine.

However, when i am trying to do the same in javascript using replace method as below, its giving syntax errors and hence fails.

```
var regex = /([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*(\s)*)/gi;
var rep = "\\u$1\\l$2";  // here it is giving error
var result = input.replace(regex,rep);
```

How to resolve this?

I know this problem can be solved using charAt() and toUppercase() method. but I want to do it using regex with replace. :)

Comment: does the article `a` should be treated as word? for ex."I have a book"

Answer (score 4):

JS regex engine does not support lower- and uppercasing operators `\u` and `\l` in the replacement patterns. Use a callback inside `String#replace`:

```js
var input = "aZ";
var regex = /([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*(\s)*)/gi;
var result = input.replace(regex, function($0,$1,$2,$3) {
  return $1.toUpperCase() + $2.toLowerCase(); 
});
console.log(result);
```

Note that you can reduce your pattern to `/([a-z])([a-z]*\s*)/gi`.